# Combobox filtrando resultados

Tags: excel, formularios, vba, filtro, combobox

Tengo el siguiente código para un combobox de VBA:

```
Cliente1.RowSource = ""
Worksheets("Datos").PivotTables("TablaDinámica2").PivotFields("Clientes").ClearAllFilters
Worksheets("Datos").PivotTables("TablaDinámica2").PivotFields("Clientes").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=Cliente1.Value
Cliente1.RowSource = "Datos!F4:F" & 4 + Range("Datos!F2").Value 'cargo los ítems del combo
Cliente1.DropDown 'despliego la lista de coincidencias
```

Cuando hago un par de busquedas me sale el siguiente error:

> Se ha producido el error '-2147417848 (80010108)' en tiemp de ejecución:
> Error de Automatización

Y se cierra el Excel inclusive.

El código esta sacado del siguiente [link](http://excelminiapps.blogspot.com/2017/10/busqueda-con-inteligente-con-combobox.html)

Por lo que he podido probar el problema aparece en cuando pongo las primeras letras del apellido, si le pongo códigos por delante y busco por el nombre o el apellido no pasa.

Ejemplo:
Listado sin códigos - (Apellidos, Nombre)
Si busco por el nombre no hay problema, pero si pongo dos letras del apellido sale el error
Listado con códigos - (0000 Apellidos, Nombre)
Puedo buscar por el nombre o por el apellido, pero si empiezo a poner el código sale el error.